# What are the benefits in refitting the Dawnstar Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On successful completion of the last mission in the Dark Brotherhood quest line you are given 20,000 gold as a reward.

You are also given the choice of putting the money towards refitting the Dawnstar Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary as opposed to keeping the money for yourself.

What are the benefits in investing your reward money in refitting the Dawnstar Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary?

Comment: I didn't know that there won't be any quests left at some point. So I spent 15k gold on the sanctuary... Now there aren't any DB quests left and I feel like I've wasted the money.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dawnstar_Sanctuary#Sanctuary_Upgrades):

> - Master Bedroom. (Contains a mannequin, bookcase, and a tribute chest)
> - Torture Chamber. (Contains four prisoners who, if 'tortured' (ie: talked to), will reveal the locations of their treasure. Each location yields between 1,000 and 2,000 gold.
> - Secret Entrance. (Creates a secret entrance through the stain glass window in the main hall, the exit leads to the south end of Dawnstar near the Khajiit traders.)
> - Alchemy Laboratory with a poison garden. (Created an Alchemy lab and a small garden with poison oriented flora growing there.)

Comment: Crap! I killed all four of the people in the torture chamber, and then piled their bodies in the middle of the room...

Answer (score 0):

You get a cool bedroom and a torture chamber where if you get the new download, you can tie them to a post. it also includes a secret door.